# General properties of cubic hypersurfaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, soft-question, complex-geometry, cubics

Is there any literature dealing with cubic hypersurfaces in full generality (over $\mathbb{C}$)? Couldn't find any.

We know everything about hyperplanes. We also know a lot of things about quadric hypersurfaces. The main tool is the relation with the associated bilinear form: this allows to describe a lot of interesting properties of the quadric, such as

1. its singular locus, which is the projectivization of the kernel of the bilinear form;
2. its linear subspaces, namely the linear subspaces of the projective space on which the bilinear form is identically zero;
3. its structure as a cone through a plane over a smooth quadric in smaller dimension.

All of this is very standard and can be found f.e. in the preliminaries of the sixth section of Griffiths and Harris' "Principles of algebraic geometry".

Do you know something along this line about *cubic* hypersurfaces? I feel like we should rely on a generalization of the bilinear form, but I'm not able to find any literature about it. Is it a much more difficult problem?

P.S.: I don't know if "cubic equations" is an appropriate tag for this...

Comment: See Daniel Huybrechts' "The geometry of cubic hypersurfaces".

Comment: In the simplest case (cubic plane curves) I suppose you could say that the Weierstrass form of the equation is in some sense the analogue of the bilinear form (in that it's a quasi-canonical algebraic form for which there are developed techniques for reading off geometric information). But taking this literally, the generalization in arbitrary dimension would be a tensor of order $3$, which is basically already the Wild West of linear algebra.

Comment: Yeah, in retrospect it's not clear from the question, but I know that order-3 tensors are a Little Bighorn. It's just that I had no idea for a different approach.

Comment: @IEm Thank you! I didn't know this.